# How to get a process's total memory usage and execution time in linux?

Tags: linux, unix, memory, process

I am making a online judge and I need this information for ranking and leaderboards. Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: for the memoryy usage i am not sure, but for time you can use the command time, so as if you would want to time a script or even a function just add time before it when you call it....e.g. time bash script_name, time function_name

Comment: @hedgehog thanks for this! For memory what I learned is to grep the running process via pid then get its memory usage. But I'm unsure about the syntax.

Comment: Well, then update your post with the syntax, and lets see it. btw you add this script that you want in a function, and then call the function with the time command, in order to get the time it needed to get it.

Answer (score 0):

The basic implementation is quite easy but online judges is more to be concerned about security first then measurement of resources.

Step by step the naive way can be written as:

1. Run the process as privileged user
2. Install all signal handlers
3. duplicate input file stream to stdin
4. create a child process
5. set resource limit values in child process
6. switch to unprivileged user in child process
7. exec the program to run in child process
8. In parent process, check for the signals sent using WIFSIGNALED and WTERMSIG etc. and determine the state of child process.

The following book shall help you study these concepts on Signals and Resource limits:

[Advanced Programming in the UNIX(R) Environment (Addison-Wesley Professional Computing Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201563177)

Comment: This is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: I am trying chroot etc for sandboxing.